# SQL "IN" CLAUSE Performance issue

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a simple SQL statement:

```
select * from Employee 
where LEFT(REPLACE(EmployeeName,'.',''),4) IN ('ABCE', 'BCDS', 'EDSC', 'XDSD', 'EFSE')
```

And I am trying to do this in Linq:

```
Employees.Where(x => new[] { "ABCE", "BCDS", "EDSC", "XDSD", "EFSE" }.Contains((x.EmployeeName.Replace(".", "").Substring(0, 4))));
```

but the SQL statement it generates is not efficient. The EmployeeName is updated everytime before comparing to the strings instead of just once:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[EmployeeID] AS [EmployeeID], 
[Extent1].[EmployeeName] AS [EmployeeName], 
[Extent1].[EmployeeTypeID] AS [EmployeeTypeID], 
[Extent1].[Active] AS [Active]
FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (N'ABCE' = (SUBSTRING(REPLACE([Extent1].[EmployeeName], N'.', N''), 0 + 1, 4))) 
OR (N'BCDS' = (SUBSTRING(REPLACE([Extent1].[EmployeeName], N'.', N''), 0 + 1, 4))) 
OR (N'EDsC' = (SUBSTRING(REPLACE([Extent1].[EmployeeName], N'.', N''), 0 + 1, 4))) 
OR (N'XDSs' = (SUBSTRING(REPLACE([Extent1].[EmployeeName], N'.', N''), 0 + 1, 4))) 
OR (N'EFSE' = (SUBSTRING(REPLACE([Extent1].[EmployeeName], N'.', N''), 0 + 1, 4)))
```

How can I make the generated SQL look more like the original sql statement? Thanks

Comment: "How can I make the generated SQL look more like the original sql statement?" - I suspect they would be the same! an IN clause is essentially a compound OR. I suggest you tell us exactly what you are trying to achieve rather than a perceived solution.

Comment: I tried both the original statement and the generated statement. The generated statement ran a lot slower.

Comment: this is strange, but i rewrote your query, and my generated sql statement is ' WHERE (SUBSTRING(REPLACE([Extent1].[Name], N'.', N''), 0 + 1, 4) IN (N'ABCE', N'BCDS', N'EDSC', N'XDSD', N'EFSE')) AND (SUBSTRING(REPLACE([Extent1].[Name], N'.', N''), 0 + 1, 4) IS NOT NULL)'. Are you sure this is the whole query?  Which EF verion you are using?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or different provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only tested it with linqpad but i think this will generate a more efficient query.

```
var result = from record in Employee
             let name = record.EmployeeName.Replace( ".", "" ).Substring( 0, 4 )
             where new[] { "ABCE", "BCDS", [...] }.Contains( name )
             select record;
```

Comment: @downvoter maybe you can explain why you downvote this answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is strange, but I rewrote your query and generated sql statement was

```
WHERE (SUBSTRING(REPLACE([Extent1].[EmployeeName], N'.', N''), 0 + 1, 4) IN (N'ABCE', N'BCDS', N'EDSC', N'XDSD', N'EFSE')) AND (SUBSTRING(REPLACE([Extent1].[Name], N'.', N'')
```

I guess that depends on used database and framework (in my case SQL Server 2008 and EF).

If you are using EF, you can force EF to use your sql statement

```
context.Set<Employee>().SqlQuery("select * from Employee where LEFT(REPLACE(EmployeeName,'.',''),4) IN ('ABCE', 'BCDS', 'EDSC', 'XDSD', 'EFSE')");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't (easily, at least) control such detail of the sql statements generation process.

But, if you are looking for the best possibile query, I would give a try to the `LIKE` operator (by making use, in your LINQ query, of a serie of `.StartsWith` conditions).

`LIKE` can use sql indexes, which is probably not happening with `SUBSTRING`and `REPLACE`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are comparing a character array instead of a string.  Try this

```
Employees.Where(x => new string[] { "ABCE", "BCDS", "EDSC", "XDSD", "EFSE" }
         .Contains((x.EmployeeName.Replace(".", "").Substring(0, 4).ToString())));
```